# is there a way to join datatables?

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I have two datatables that comes from different database servers, the first looks like this:

[structure from first dataTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zmm4O.png)

it shows how many clients each salesperson visited in the specified date.
The second dataTable looks like this:

[structure of second dataTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MJeK.png)

it shows how many customer the saleperson was supposed to visit.

As i said this data comes from two different servers, i need to do something like a join in database with the key fields (SLPRSNID AND DAYOFWEEK) in order to show in a report the compliance percentage of each salesperson.

My report application is made in VB.NET for desktop environment.
Thanks in advance
btw sorry for my bad english

Comment: Is there any reason you did not JOIN them in SQL?  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: because the first table comes from a thirdparty server where we have our movile app for salespersons (it's mysql btw) and the second one comes from our sql server

Comment: I've never done it so I don't know the details but it possible to add linked servers to a SQL Server instance, so that you could do the join in a query to your SQL Server.

Comment: this can't be done with linq or something like that in visual basic? i do not have admin privileges in the SQL server.

Comment: If the two datatables are in memory, you can just add a DataColumn to the first one and use a loop to copy the data over.

Comment: You are only missing the column called "Clients" on the second picture that is missing from the first. So you only need to make one column to the first table.

Comment: Hey Chillzy y forgot to mention something my fault, the column of the dayofweek is important beacuse the idea is filter from database with a date range, in the example i only put one day but they can be more, and each salesperson has different clients to visit per day.

Comment: SSS i think that would work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use linq to datasets to accomplish what you are looking for, if that is to get the two datatables into one flattened result set.  See this for a description and example: [Cross Table Query of Datatables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/cross-table-queries-linq-to-dataset)

If you want to maintain a relationship for some reason, consider designing a dataset with the two datatables and a data relation to join them.  That will create functions to GetChildRows from the parent, and GetParentRow from the children.

**Update #1** - Try this to convert your query result into a datatable.  [Creating a DataTable From a Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/creating-a-datatable-from-a-query-linq-to-dataset)

```
Dim boundTable As DataTable = query.CopyToDataTable()
```

Comment: Thnaks, linq query worked, but i have problems casting it to a datatable.

Comment: I've edited the answer to show a possible solution to converting your result to a datatable.

Answer (score 1):

Found out `Merge(DataTable)` Method from MSDN. Hope it will solve your problem
[Merge()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.merge.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Also #SSS suggested answer can be accepted for your problem

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong, i think merge works for datatable with the same structure, like an UNION clause i guess, i think i will gowith #SSS answer for this time

Comment: yes your correct. merge mostly use for datatables which have largely similar schemas